# How to Create One Category from 2 Datasets in Python

Tags: python, dataset, categories, jupyter-notebook

I have two data sets that both have data in  it like follows:

Data set 1:

```
Country Year   Cause  Gender    Deaths
2090    2011    A000    1       70340
2090    2010    A001    2       53449
2090    2009    A002    1       1731
2090    2008    A003    2       1270
2090    2007    A004    1       148
2310    2011    A000    2       172
2310    2010    A001    1       24
2310    2009    A002    2       20
2310    2008    A003    1       27
2660    2013    A004    2       21
2660    2012    A005    1       88
2660    2011    A006    2       82
```

Data set 2:

```
Country Year   Cause  Gender    Deaths
2090    1999    B529    1       557
2090    1995    A001    2       234
2090    1996    B535    1       29
2090    1997    A002    2       33
2090    1998    B546    1       3224
2090    1999    B556    2       850
2310    1995    B555    1       319
2310    1996    A003    2       143
2310    1997    B563    1       251
2310    1998    B573    2       117
2660    1997    B561    1       244
2660    1998    A002    2       115
2660    1999    A001    1       10
2660    2000    B569    2       2
```

I need to create categories on the Cause column codes which are for causes of death. But I need to make this category from using these combined causes from both data sets separately e.g.

Road Traffic Accidents Category: From Data set 1: A001, A003

Road Traffic Accidents Category: From Data set 2: B569, B555

and the causes from both of these must be included in the Road Traffic Accidents Category.

They must be included in each category for each data set (not combined) like: Road Traffic Accidents: A001, A003, B569, B555

This is because say for example A001. In Data set 1 A001 is for Car Accidents, but in Data set 2 A001 means Heart Attack and I don't want Heart Attack in the Road Traffic Accidents category. But when the category is made from both data sets (i.e. Road Traffic Accidents: A001, A003, B569, B555) then A001 from both data sets is included in the Road Traffic Accidents category.

The purpose of this question is to see how different categories differ over the years in terms of deaths - I am not allowed to combine both data sets manually not on Python. I am also not allowed to use any of the common packages such as Pandas, Numpy, etc.

Thank you for help in advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my understanding of your problem is (correct me if I'm wrong), you have two datasets which both have a "Cause" column/variable. But the encoding of this "Cause" column in two datasets are different.

In Dataset1, perhaps the encoding says:

```
Road Traffic Accidents Category: A001, A003
Heart Attack Category: C001, C002  #made up encoding
```

In Dataset2, perhaps the encoding says:

```
Road Traffic Accidents Category:  B569, B555
Heart Attack Category: A001
Hurricane Cause of Death Category: E941 # made up encoding
```

What you want is to create a consistent category to cause encoding mapping which works for two datasets.

I personally think python dictionary is the right data structure for this task. I assume you can load the category-cause mapping for both datasets.

```
data1_cat_cause = {'Road Traffic Accidents': ['A001', 'A003'],
                   'Heart Attack': ['C001', 'C002']}
data2_cat_cause = {'Road Traffic Accidents': ['B569', 'B555'],
                   'Heart Attack': ['A001'], 
                   'Hurricane Cause of Death': ['E941']}

category_combined = set(data1_cat_cause.keys()) | set(data2_cat_cause.keys())
cat_cause_combined = {}
for category in category_combined:
    cat_cause_combined[category] = {'Dataset1':data1_cat_cause.get(category),'Dataset2':data2_cat_cause.get(category)}
```

This would yield following information stored in the "cat_cause_combined" variable:

```
                          Dataset1 encoding       Dataset2 encoding
Road Traffic Accidents  :  ['A001', 'A003']       ['B569', 'B555']
Heart Attack            :  ['C001', 'C002']       ['A001']
Hurricane Cause of Death:   None                  ['E941']
```

I hope I understand your problem correctly and I hope this solution solves your problem.

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much! I think you have understood what I am saying :)  But when i try I am getting errors. This is actually what it looks like for road traffic accidents

Comment: Dataset1_cat_cause = {'Road Traffic Accidents': ['V01’, ‘V02’, ‘V03’, ‘V04’, ‘V05’, ‘V06’, ‘V07’, ‘V08’, ‘V09’, ‘V10’, ‘V11’, ‘V12’, ‘V13’, ‘V14’, ‘V15’, ‘V16’, ‘V17’,
Dataset2_Data_ICD9_cat_cause = {'Road Traffic Accidents': ['B47’]}

Comment: I get this error:   File "<ipython-input-49-2b8e5308e583>", line 3
    Dataset2_Data_ICD9_cat_cause = {'Road Traffic Accidents': ['B47’]}
                                                                      ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: Sorry I fixed that :) Trying the second code block now

Comment: I think it has worked!! Thank you so much - I have been stuck on this for so long! How can I check that it worked? Just to be sure

Comment: I did cat_cause_combined and it came up with the dictionary! :)

Comment: So just please making sure that this has done the in your example:

Comment: Dataset 1 only has the causes A001 and A003 in road traffic and C001 and C002 in Heart Attack
data2_cat_cause = {'Road Traffic Accidents': ['B569', 'B555'],
                   'Heart Attack': ['A001'], 
                   'Hurricane Cause of Death': ['E941']}

Comment: Sorry it's not letting me edit and delete comments for some reason but what I meant to say was:  
Dataset 1 only has the causes A001 and A003 in road traffic and C001 and C002 in Heart Attack, A001, A003, C001 and C002 are not coming from Dataset 2? Is that correct?

Comment: And the same for Dataset 2 only has the causes B569, B555 in road traffic and A001 on Heart Attack from Dataset 2 and not Dataset 1

Comment: Yes. I think the output you got by running that code with the examples I made up is correct. If one category only exists in one dataset, it will simply give the keyword None as a representation, which is the case with "Hurricane" category, since only Dataset2 has this category, so cat_cause_combined['Hurricane']['Dataset1'] would be None. A high-level understanding of this way of organizing info, is using a nested dictionary. The outer level key is just the "category" you cared about, the inner level key indicates which dataset the encoding comes from.

Comment: :) Yes definitely, how can I do that?

Comment: Here is the link to "how to accept answer" : http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers  (Thanks I appreciate it)

Comment: Sorry about the delay for accepting (got a bit busy sorry). I think I have accepted it (I pressed the tick) :) And you are very welcome, it's my pleasure - thank you for a great working answer the first time to a complicated question that I needed help fast on!!! :) :)